# how to use vectors pushback function to store things from a file?

Tags: c++, file, for-loop, vector

suppose i have a file that contain the following size of the students, first name ,last name,gpa

file format:

```
2
sam harris 3
john witt 2
```

however i am confused how can i push back the first name, last name and gpa into a vector?

i tried the following implementation but still getting it wrong:

```
 ifstream mycin;
 float *Pcgpa = new float[size];  string PfirstN, PlastN;
 float Avg; float sum = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i <size; i++)
 {
   mycin >> PfirstN[i] >> PlastN[i] >> Pcgpa[i];
   firstN.push_back(PfirstN);
   lastN.push_back(PlastN);
   cgpa.push_back(Pcgpa);
   sum += cgpa[i];
 }
```

Comment: You are using arrays (float[size]), a vector would be declared as `std::vector<float> Pcgpa`.

Comment: Where's the code to read `size`?

Comment: How are `firstN` and `lastN` declared? Post a [mcve] as required here please.

Answer (score 1):

Normally (but who knows when students are being asked to do exercises) you would declare a struct to hold one line of data

```
struct Student
{
    string first_name;
    string last_name;
    float gpa;
};
```

Then you would declare a vector of those structs

```
vector<Student> students;
```

Then you would write your loop and push back onto the vector

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
     Student s;
     mycin >> s.first_name >> s.last_name >> s.gpa;
     students.push_back(s);
     sum += s.gpa;
}
```

PS you are overusing abbreviations (IMHO). It doesn't help with the readability of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Several things to note:

a) The code is not complete. Please, post complete and preferably compiling source code.

b) Why would you mix std::vector and arrays? (push_back only exists in std::vector but you're allocating Pcgpa as a standard C array) and you don't need size beforehand. Also, if you use vectors and read until the end of the file, you don't need Pcgpa.

c) You need to input to PfirstN not to PfirstN[i]. You read a whole string, not a letter. Also, accessing PfirstN[i] with i > 0 on an empty string is a no-no.

This should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int size= 0;
    cin >> size;

    vector<string> vectorOfFirstNames;
    vector<string> vectorOfLastNames;
    vector<float> vectorOfcgpa;
    float sum= 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        float cgpa= 0.0;

        cin >> firstName >> lastName >> cgpa;
        vectorOfFirstNames.push_back(firstName);
        vectorOfLastNames.push_back(lastName);
        vectorOfcgpa.push_back(cgpa);
        sum+= cgpa;
    }

    // Print data
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << "First name: " << vectorOfFirstNames[i] << " - Last name: " << vectorOfLastNames[i] << " - cgpa: " << vectorOfcgpa[i] << endl;
    }

    // Please don't divide by zero ;)
    float avg= size > 0 ? sum/size : 0;
    cout << "Avg: " << avg << endl;
    cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
}
```